# How can I add a SearchBar in MenuBarExtra with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, searchable, menubarextra

macOS 13.0+, Apple introduce a new api named MenuBarExtra which can add a menubar in macOS.
But I can't add a searchable protocol into the content to add a search view ?

```swift
@main
struct AppWithMenuBarExtra: App {
    @AppStorage("showMenuBarExtra") private var showMenuBarExtra = true

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        MenuBarExtra(
            "App Menu Bar Extra", systemImage: "star",
            isInserted: $showMenuBarExtra)
        {
            NavigationLink {
               Text("Search")
            }.searchable()
        }
    }
}
```

I expect a search bar can show in the menuBar

Comment: `MenuBarExtra` cannot show a searchbar in the menu bar with the default `menu` style. But you can show a window containing a searchbar with the `window` style

Comment: yes,I have solved this problem, thank you guys

Comment: Please post your solution, to help others.

Comment: Hey Duke, thanks for posting, really great. Even better would be posting your solution as an answer, and marking it as accepted.

Comment: ok, It is more clearly and friendly for others. I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem, here is my solution:

We can not add a `NavigationLink` and its protocol `searchable` into a `MenuBarExtra` scene for adding a search view, but we can add a `TextField` as a searchBar in `MenuBarExtra` when we set the modifier `.menuBarExtraStyle` to `.window`:

```
@main
struct AppWithMenuBarExtra: App {
    @AppStorage("showMenuBarExtra") private var showMenuBarExtra = true
    @State private var searchText: String
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        MenuBarExtra(
            "App Menu Bar Extra", systemImage: "star",
            isInserted: $showMenuBarExtra) {
            TextField("Input the search text",text: $searchText)
              .onSubmit {
            // do search action
            }
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window) // open item as popover window
    }
}
```

Comment: @soundflix thanks  for fixing my answer that had some grammatical errors